# Differentiable structure of an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

Let $ V $ an $ \mathbb{R} $-vector space, we can prove that $ V $ is a manifold. Using the topology compatible with $ \mathbb {R} ^ n $ and defining the chart $ (V, \phi_B) $ where $ \phi_B: V \to \mathbb {R} ^ n $, $\phi_B(v)=(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$, $B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a base of $V$ and $v=\lambda_1 
 v_1+...+ \lambda_nv_n$. I want to show that this structure does not depend on the base, that is, for another base $B'=\{v_1', ..., v_n'\}$ when we define $\phi_{B'}$ we have the compatibility of the charts $\phi$ and $\phi'$, i.e, $\phi \circ \phi'^{-1}$ and $\phi' \circ \phi^{-1}$ are smooth.

To find the composition explicitly I thought of introducing the base change, but I can't conclude that the compositions are smooth.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the charts you define are all *globally* defined, that is, they have domain $V$. Hence to prove that change of coordinates are smooth is suffices to compute

$$
\varphi_B \circ \varphi_{B'}^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n
$$

and prove it is smooth (the other composition is automatic by interchanging $B$ with $B'$).

As you say, this is a base change. But a simpler observation suffices: this map is a composition of linear ones, hence linear itself, and so it is smooth.

Comment: So, I was forgetting linearity.

Comment: Surely you can explicitly compute this in terms of $B$ and $B'$, and then calculate directional derivatives etc. My point is rather that *for euclidean space*, we already know that linear maps are smooth in the much simpler sense of multivariable calculus, which is what we need anyway.